# Delphi XE TMediaPlayer "invalid floating point operation" on Windows 8/10

Tags: delphi, windows-8, windows-10, invalidoperationexception

We have a program that plays a video in a corner of a form and it has been working for several years on W7, however some of our customers are now using W8 and W10.  When we play a video that works on W7, on W8 or W10 the player creates the exception "invalid floating point operation" and hangs.

Has anyone seen this error or have any ideas of what it may be?  I created a version with message boxes at various points in the code as I cannot install Delphi on these computers and the error occurs when I call TMediaPlayer.Play

Up until this point, every property seems to be set correctly.  The exception looks like a division by zero?  Maybe?

Thanks
Trevor

Comment: Basically, mask floating point exceptions

Comment: This worked, it wasn't actually a division by zero error, but the video plays (I don't know what caused the error inside the player code, nothing much I can do about it anyway).  Now I read the current mask before calling play, then then restore it as I don't want to mask these errors in my own code.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Now it has come back, intermittently.  I ultimately changed my code to mask the errors at startup and restore at close, masking errors just before playing didn't always work.  On a few machines (1 or 2) the error is back again, so I have tried masking the errors at startup and masking again just before playing (restoring at close).  Is the mask "global" and anything on the computer can change it (similar questions here seem to indicate this)?  Could another program be changing this mask, bringing the error back?  Are my thoughts correct?  Just hoping to learn something from all this :-)

Comment: Hard to comment without more detail